# User Idle time in Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to check how much time passed since last user input occurence (preffered way - in python) on Linux (lucid - 10.4)

I know that this is easy in normal way (just using XScreenSaverQueryInfo), but the tricky part is that I don't have x11/extensions/scrnsaver.h header and I HAVE to do that some other way (even if I install needed package I cannot install packeges on 100 other computers on which it will work - I don't have permission to do that).

Comment: you don't need to have header files on the 100 machines you target, only on the one you build your application on.

Comment: Are you saying that the other 100 computers aren't running X11? Or are you saying that they don't have `scrnsaver.h` ?

Comment: they have X11 but from what I have found: "XScreenSaver framework isn't installed by default", also when I tried to create python module from c the compiler shouts that x11/extensions/scrnsaver.h does not exists - and it doesn't (I checked in usr/libs)

Comment: You just need the header on development machine, resulting binary will work fine on all machines.

Comment: Perhaps this should be asked on [SU]

Comment: I already installed lacking package - not only headers are missing after installation of whole package (sudo apt-get install libxss-dev) I can see much more things - my old solution works now, but before I will test it on other computers weeks will pass. But still I would prefere doing this some other way.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative based on X screensaver is [xssstate from suckless-tools](https://tools.suckless.org/x/xssstate/):

```
xssstate -i
```

Answer (score 3):

using xprintidle

requirements:
`sudo apt-get install xprintidle`

usage from command line:
`xprintidle`

or, in seconds:
`` echo $((`xprintidle` / 1000)) ``

or from python:

```
milliseconds_string = os.popen("xprintidle").read()
seconds = int(milliseconds_string)/1000
```

Answer (score 1):

In deps of internet I found something like this, and it looks like working - but still not perfect solution because it returns much more info than I need and also the number near which is proper value is not constant (it differs in other system):

`ls -l /dev/pts | fgrep username`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would to be use the unix command `w`, this gives the idle time of all users (with the exception of the w command which appears to not reset idle time)

the `w` command also has a few flags -s and -f to show a short format and not print the hostname giving you slightly less information to find the idle time. I was able to get it down to

```
> w -sf | grep user
jxw1234  pts/5      6.00s w -sf
```

This also gives idle time down to seconds so is more precise than `ls -l /dev/pts`.

From this point it should be pretty simple to run the command using python's system interface and apply a regex to pull out the time in various formats.

EDIT:
Using this [w command get idle time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191436/linux-w-command-get-idle-time-in-seconds) i was able to get it down to the following result.

```
>w | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $1,$5 }}' | grep username
jxw1234 1.00s
```