# How to get the time when I last used the computer

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xorg

In GNU/Linux on *xorg* session, what I want to do is to get how many seconds have passed since I stopped working with the computer (i.e. no keys pressed and/or cursor moved).

Running in the background, the script below will display `secs` in the status bar.

But the question is what `THE_COMMAND` will be.

```sh
While true; do
    last_touched="$(THE_COMMAND)"
    now="$(date +%s)"
    secs=$((now - last_touched))
    echo "${secs} seconds ago"
    sleep 3
done
```

Comment: If you _telnet_ into your system from another computer, does this count as "already working"?

Comment: I hope I get what you mean correctly, but unless I press keys or move cursor using mouse/touchpad on the local machine, the computer will be assumed idle.

Comment: This would likely exclude a telnet access, but still applies to both X - session and a login in text console, without X-server, doesn't it? But since you tagged the question _xorg_, you are probably only interested in X-sessions anyway.

Comment: If by "a login in text console, without X-server" you mean in a tty environment, I just checked and it threw the error: couldn't open display.

Comment: Of course, because the idea of a display does not make sense for an X-application, if you don't have an X-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember asking the same question a while back.
Here is what I found,

```
last -aiF -n 1 userName
```

command can give you the current session.

When combined with `awk` you can get the result as follows

```
$ last -aiF -n2 username
username  :1           Wed Apr 21 13:09:00 2021   still logged in                       0.0.0.0
username  :1           Wed Apr 21 07:28:47 2021 - down                      (05:39)     0.0.0.0


$ last -aiF -n 2 ogulcan | awk '{print $10}'
in
(05:39)
```

the lines here are the session times.

These times are counted as `now - first boot login`

But I believe these does not work best for you.
So here is the 8 year old question that may be helpful to you.

[User Idle time in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068887/user-idle-time-in-linux)

Using python you can calculate the idle time passed. Maybe this way, you can simply get what you want with python.

Comment: The link you included above contained what I was looking for, being ```xprintidle```. Thanks.

Comment: `xprintidle` works only if you have a X Window Session open. If this is not the case (say, because you work with a text terminal or a different window manager), this won't help you.

Comment: What @user1934428 said is mentioned in the link I added. I believe that it works for  @ nino. For terminals, I am curious too :)

Comment: I'm actually on _xorg_ and they work fine, both `xprintidle` and `xssstate`.